# Need to login to Skype with a proxy

Tags: networking, firefox, proxy, internet-explorer, skype

I'm in a boarding house as a student and my internet connection is established with a LAN cable. We were told to configure Firefox or IE with that specific proxy server (example 154.36.2.332) and port (example 6258). So far so good this is working. However Skype, or Spotify is not. Even when I manually insert the server name and port it is still not working. I suppose they blocked it. 
Is there anyway to make it work?

Comment: use a global vpn instead of a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

In general Skype auto detects your Proxy server,if You Decide to use Skype through Proxy Follow this instructions :

1.Open **Skype** Navigate to **Tools** --> **Options**

2.Click On **advanced** --> Click **Connection**

[image: Skype Sample Image]

3.Enter the Details of your **host,port details** etc

4 Enter Your Username and Password and login

Image credit : Skype community

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this has not helped and I tried that also before. Is it possible that Skype, Spotify or µTorrent are all blocked and that there is nothing I can do about it? Or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by navigating to **Tools** > **Options** & go to the circled area, then fill in the given proxy `IP:PORT` as seen below; (I've taken the same IP & port as mentioned in example. Make sure you select **SOCKS5** from the dropdown & enable the proxy authentication if necessary (if any user & password involved only).
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this has not helped and I tried that also before. Is it possible that Skype, Spotify or µTorrent are all blocked and that there is nothing I can do about it? Or am I just missing something?

Comment: This is the only setting available if you're using a proxy. As you suspect, I assume the proxy server may be filtered with rules as to which ports should work and which should not. I found [this](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA148/which-ports-need-to-be-open-to-use-skype-for-windows-desktop) article in skype support